# what is the code of mouse leave and mouse out in angularjs.without jquery?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in Angularjs. What are the events equivalent to mouseout and mouseleave in jQuery?

My problem is related to [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ItemBlur/) tutorial

I am trying to convert from jQuery to Angularjs. 
If cursor is over one is active and other is blur. It's a function in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The events you want are `ng-mouseout` and `ng-mouseleave`
[Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave) are the docs.